# SocketTimeoutException after ServerHelloDone in TLS connection

Tags: java, ssl

I have a server made using SSLServerSocket. The server receives connections from lots of other servers. The other servers are from third parties. It always works well for all servers, except for one of them. The typical ssl debug log is like the following:

```
WorkerThread-2, READ: Unknown-3.3 Handshake, length = 116
*** ClientHello, Unknown-3.3
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1513485218 bytes = { 151, 69, 77, 255, 242, 138, 61, 245, 71, 237, 98, 49, 92, 122, 152, 21, 229, 164, 150, 171, 11, 177, 238, 234, 63, 168, 90, 151 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0xc0:0x28, Unknown 0xc0:0x27, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x3d, Unknown 0x0:0x3c, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp384r1, secp256r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension signature_algorithms, data: 00:12:06:01:06:03:04:01:05:01:02:01:04:03:05:03:02:03:02:02
Unsupported extension type_35, data:
Unsupported extension type_23, data:
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Created:  [Session-180, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1513485220 bytes = { 74, 28, 71, 12, 232, 178, 237, 132, 60, 224, 123, 53, 189, 12, 182, 240, 206, 94, 159, 96, 89, 29, 71, 144, 161, 254, 84, 32 }
Session ID:  {90, 54, 244, 164, 39, 152, 221, 223, 132, 77, 169, 99, 15, 202, 26, 191, 213, 70, 91, 125, 141, 91, 159, 248, 11, 145, 254, 187, 97, 178, 14, 233}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
      [... certificate chain follows ...]
***
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS
Cert Authorities:
<CN=QuoVadis Root CA 2 G3, O=QuoVadis Limited, C=BM>
<CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root G3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US>
    .... many more cert authorities
WorkerThread-2, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 16384
*** ServerHelloDone
WorkerThread-2, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1403
WorkerThread-2, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 3983
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
    ... client certificate chain follows
...
    ... connection proceeds normally and suceeds
```

As you can see the handshake seems normal, the server requests the client to authenticate through a certificate, and the client sends it. However, for only one of the third party servers (which I have no access to), the handshake proceeds like the following:

```
WorkerThread-2, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 159
*** ClientHello, Unknown-3.3
RandomCookie:  GMT: -750761141 bytes = { 238, 28, 230, 74, 9, 73, 28, 198, 222, 183, 234, 204, 37, 117, 50, 44, 71, 133, 93, 240, 66, 157, 241, 152, 75, 168, 0, 174 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0xc0:0x2b, Unknown 0xc0:0x2f, Unknown 0xcc:0xa9, Unknown 0xcc:0xa8, Unknown 0xc0:0x2c, Unknown 0xc0:0x30, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x9c, Unknown 0x0:0x9d, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Unsupported extension server_name, [host_name: smtp3.myserverdns.com]
Unsupported extension type_23, data:
Unsupported extension type_35, data:
Unsupported extension signature_algorithms, data: 00:12:04:03:08:04:04:01:05:03:08:05:05:01:08:06:06:01:02:01
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {unknown curve 29, secp256r1, secp384r1}
***
%% Created:  [Session-189, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1513485240 bytes = { 91, 241, 167, 85, 144, 140, 202, 57, 192, 1, 43, 95, 77, 164, 68, 210, 170, 37, 114, 50, 237, 255, 17, 205, 131, 74, 242, 21 }
Session ID:  {90, 54, 244, 184, 141, 168, 116, 151, 23, 155, 13, 108, 239, 23, 28, 117, 51, 182, 85, 174, 138, 132, 254, 29, 235, 231, 30, 184, 40, 27, 38, 145}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  [... certificate chain follows ...]
***
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS
Cert Authorities:
<CN=QuoVadis Root CA 2 G3, O=QuoVadis Limited, C=BM>
<CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root G3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US>
    .... many more cert authorities
WorkerThread-2, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 16384
*** ServerHelloDone
WorkerThread-2, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1403
WorkerThread-2, handling exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
WorkerThread-2, called close()
WorkerThread-2, called closeInternal(true)
WorkerThread-2, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
WorkerThread-2, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
WorkerThread-2, called close()
WorkerThread-2, called closeInternal(true)
WorkerThread-2, called close()
WorkerThread-2, called closeInternal(true)
```

As you can see, inmediately after the `ServerHelloDone` no response from client arrives and a socket timeout occurs. In fact, the timeout is always after only 1.5 seconds aprox. after the start of the handshake.

Why is the socket timing out after such a short time? I think something in the server hello is not ok for the client, but I have no idea about what it can be. Do you see any significant difference between the two ssl debug logs that justifies the failure? I've been searching in the Internet for hours with no luck.

Comment: Why are you setting a 1.5 second read timeout?

Comment: I am not setting the timeout value, it usually times out after 1.5 secs. The timeout value used is the JVM or system default. Bear in mind that this only happens with one client , and the configuration is the same for all connections.

Comment: It's not the HelloDone which contains literally nothing but the message prefix. It might be something else in the first flight, which is all sent together before the client responds, although all content-related errors I can think of should produce an alert or at least a FIN or RST, or it could be the first flight itself. If you can, get a wire trace with wireshark tcpdump or similar and see if you are getting a TCP-level ack for the first flight. If so you can't proceed without looking on the client system; if not look at both the client system and the network path between it and you.

Comment: [@dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085)  I would try your suggestion, but I am not sure exactly where to look. What do you mean by first flight?

Comment: joanlofe: I didn't get pinged for your comment even though it looks like I should have, but fortunately I was intrigued enough I came back to check on my own. See non-answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Meta: not an answer but much too long for comments; I will delete in a few days.

In many protocols a 'flight' of transmission units is a group of several units that are sent together. In SSL/TLS handshake protocol, the client sends one message (ClientHello) and then the server sends multiple messages which are its first flight, and since the client's flight is trivial (one message) I simply label the server's first flight the first flight. It consists of ServerHello always, Certificate usually, ServerKeyExchange sometimes, CertificateRequest rarely, and ServerHelloDone always. After this normally the client sends a second flight of several messages, and then the server a second flight ditto. See the diagram on page 36 of [rfc5246 (scroll down)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.3) or equivalent in earlier versions.

Clearly something about this first flight caused a problem; the cause could either be one of the messages *in* it, or the lower-level (TCP) transmission which consists of either a single TLS record or a few contiguous ones; in your case it is two records, per the log lines

```
... WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 16384
... WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1403
```

TLS handshake messages can be packed into records but TLS records are limited to 16384 and the combined messages of your first flight exceeded that so it requires two records. Looking at a trace of the TCP behavior, which is normally visible only at the 'wire' (physical or logical network) level, can help us distinguish.

TCP is too complicated a protocol for me to explain here if you do not already know about it. There are probably hundreds of books about the 'TCP/IP' protocol family or 'stack', and quite possibly millions of websites. For my money [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) is fairly rigorous and thorough while still being not insanely difficult. But in short once a connection is established, when one endpoint sends some data (in one or more segment-sized datagrams, which do not necessarily match upper-level data units in this case TLS records) if the other endpoint receives this data correctly it will normally respond with a TCP header in which the 'ACK' value has been incremented past the range of 'SEQ' values in the transmitted data. If we do see such an ACK value then we know the transmitted data was delivered to the TLS endpoint on the remote system, and if you see an ACK for the entire flight we know the flight was delivered and any immediately subsequent problem is a result of the remote endpoint processing the messages.

OTOH if we don't see such an ACK, it means the remote host didn't receive the segments of data; in the past this sometimes meant loss due to link errors or delays, but on the modern Internet where links are almost always reliable and fast it almost always means the data was *discarded*. In particular if there is a mismatch between your system, the remote system, or any of the network links in between as to the 'MTU' size, that is the 'maximum transmission unit', it can result in datagrams being discarded, and thus transmission failing. TCP has a mechanism that is intended to correct this, called PMTU (path MTU) discovery, but it depends on ICMP, and in the modern Internet many people block ICMP because they think, usually but not always wrongly, it is a security problem.

Wireshark (on Windows, Mac, and some Linuxes/Unixes) is a (very) complete GUI-based tool for capturing and decoding network data. `tcpdump` is a more basic command-line tool for the same purpose on some Unixes, usually including Linux; some other Unixes have similar tools with different names and different details. You didn't mention what OS you are using so I wasn't specific.

`tcpdump` by default decodes the IP and TCP headers, so you can simply look at the seq and ack values shown for each line=packet, bearing in mind the direction of each at the IP level; if there is other activity at the same time on your host and network, `tcpdump` has options to filter which packets are captured and displayed, making it a good deal easier to read. `tcpdump` also has options to capture to a file or files (commonly named something.pcap) instead of displaying. Wireshark usually decodes multiple protocol layers for each frame, so you need to look at the 'Internet Protocol' and 'Transmission Control Protocol' layers in the packet detail pane for each packet; it can save to a capture file *as well as* displaying, and has (different) options to filter both while capturing and while displaying. If you aren't able to figure out the trace yourself, putting the text output of `tcpdump` or equivalent in your Q is probably sufficient, but putting a binary pcap file somewhere accessible might be needed.

Comment: Wow! Good explanation, thanks a lot! I use wireshark and found out some interesting things, not in the log above. For example, that the client is sending a fatal alert of type protocol_version, likely caused by a previous message from the server that is not an SSL message. Now I am trying to find out why the server sends that non-SSL message between two SSL messages. I will try to post the wireshark log later, so you can see it.